# VB.Net Create a ImageGenerator process

Tags: vb.net, image, for-loop, process, generator

I want to know how can i make a process..

Im actually doing this with a For like this:

```
        timeCount = 0
        Timer.Start()
        Dim Count As Integer = 1, next As Boolean
        For Each dataRow As DataRow In DataBase.Rows
            nextImage = False
            Do While nextImage = False
                Try
                    Dim Ext As String = ".png"
                    If rbJPG.Checked = True Then Ext = ".jpg"
                    GenerateImage(dataRow, ImageFrom, FBD.SelectedPath, Ext, Count)
                    nextImage = True
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Timer.Stop()
                    Dim Result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                    If Result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Ignore Then
                        Timer.Start()
                        nextImage = True
                    ElseIf Result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Retry Then
                        Timer.Start()
                        nextImage = False
                    ElseIf Result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Abort Then
                        prgGenerate.Value = 0
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End Try
            Loop
            Count += 1
            prgGenerate.Increment(1)
        Next
```

But this colapse my program and uses a lot of RAM.

I cant show nothing during the process, for example: Elapsed Time. And the timer never start.

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: You need to put that "work" into a different thread.  Look at using the BackgroundWorker() control.  Also, what is the Timer actually doing?...

Comment: Counting seconds.. i use it to get elapsed time.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me how you're setting the `ImageFrom` variable, but here's a simple example using the BackgroundWorker():

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    timeCount = 0
    Me.Invoke(Sub()
                  Timer.Start()
              End Sub)
    Dim Count As Integer = 1, nextImage As Boolean
    For Each dataRow As DataRow In Database.Rows
        nextImage = False
        Do While nextImage = False
            Try
                Dim Ext As String = ".png"
                If rbJPG.Checked = True Then Ext = ".jpg"
                GenerateImage(dataRow, ImageFrom, FBD.SelectedPath, Ext, Count)
                nextImage = True
            Catch ex As Exception
                Me.Invoke(Sub()
                              Timer.Stop()
                              Dim Result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                              If Result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Ignore Then
                                  Timer.Start()
                                  nextImage = True
                              ElseIf Result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Retry Then
                                  Timer.Start()
                                  nextImage = False
                              ElseIf Result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Abort Then
                                  prgGenerate.Value = 0
                                  Exit For
                              End If
                          End Sub)
            End Try
        Loop
        Count += 1
        Me.Invoke(Sub()
                      prgGenerate.Increment(1)
                  End Sub)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    MessageBox.Show("Done!")
End Sub
```

You'd start the background thread with:

```
BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
```